# trouble with installing cakephp on localhost wamp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RunOP.png)hello fellas triyng to Installing cakephp on wamp
and i am 
getting following error

**require( 'C:\wamp\www\cake\config\bootstrap.php'**

please 
help me out

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide enough details how you are trying to install Cakephp.

It is strongly recommended to install it via composer. Have a look at this documentation.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#installing-cakephp

By the question you have asked, you sound quite new to Cakephp. If you follow a tutorial of how-to-start by Cakephp might help you get started with the framework. Have a look at
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

Comment: yes i used composer to install. Directly inside wamp/www using comand intreface. Then I ran it locally on localhost and it displayed two errors, one of them I solved by enabling read write mode on apache but still I'm getting above error displayed. Do you want me put screen shot of error?

Comment: yes i used composer to install. Directly inside wamp/www using comand intreface. Then I ran it locally on localhost and it displayed two errors, one of them I solved by enabling read write mode on apache but still I'm getting above error displayed. Do you want me put screen shot of error?

Comment: Yes. Show a screenshot. Show me the root directory also of the application

Comment: just look **above** where, **title of question is saying** in **blue** "**enter image description here** " click on it. and root directory is **" c://wamp/www/cake "**